# Asynchronous function not executing sequentially inside loop even though used deferred object

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, deferred

I am having one asynchronous function which is running in the loop. This function is creating some HTML buttons with dates. dates should come sequentially. But finally dates are coming in very random order. Here is my code

```
   var getDatesAvailable = function() {
    var weekDays = masterConfigurations[0].DaysOfWeek.results;
    var advancedDays = masterConfigurations[0].DaysToShow;
    var todaysDate = new Date();
    var futureDate = new Date(todaysDate);
    futureDate.setDate(todaysDate.getDate() + advancedDays);
    var availableDates = returnFinalDates(todaysDate, futureDate, weekDays);
    var formattedDates = [];
    $(availableDates).each(function(i, e) {
        var tDate = commonOperations.pad(e.getDate(), 2);
        var tMonth = commonOperations.pad((e.getMonth() + 1), 2);
        var isoDate = e.getFullYear() + "-" + tMonth + "-" + tDate + "T00:00:00.000z";
        formattedDates.push({
            "displayDate": (tDate + "/" + tMonth),
            "dateObj": isoDate
        });
    });
    var dateButtons = "";
    var buttonDates = [];
    var schoolCode = $('#selectedSchoolAddress').data('schoolCode') || "";
    $(formattedDates).each(function(i, e) {
        var startDate = new Date(e.dateObj).toISOString();
        var endDate = e.dateObj.split("T")[0];
        endDate = (new Date(endDate + "T23:59:59.000z")).toISOString();

        commonOperations.queryList("ITFS_Transact_School_Visits", "?$filter=((ITFSVisitDate gt '" + startDate + "') and (ITFSVisitDate lt '" + endDate + "') and (ITFSVisitSchoolCode eq '" + schoolCode + "'))", false).then(function(bookings) {
            var maxBookings = masterConfigurations[0].MaxBookingsPerSession;
            var bookingsAlreadyHad = bookings.d.results.length || 0;

            if (bookingsAlreadyHad >= maxBookings) {
                dateButtons = dateButtons + '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default dateButton add10Margin" data-date="' + e.dateObj + '" disabled="disabled">' + formattedDates[i].displayDate + '</button>'
            } else {
                dateButtons = dateButtons + '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default dateButton add10Margin" data-date="' + e.dateObj + '">' + formattedDates[i].displayDate + '</button>'
            }
            $("#displayDates").html(dateButtons);
        });
    });

};
```

I have tried so many ways. Even I am specifying to ajax call that dont execute asynchronously by passing `false` as parameter. But still not working. How to control this? or is there anything to achieve using closures or anything?
I logged index of the loop it is also not coming sequentially randomly coming.

Comment: You should **definitely** look into using [Javascript Promises](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/). If nothing else, what I linked to is a great read which I highly recommend, but it talks in depth about *sequential* deferred function invocation - which by the sounds of things is exactly what you need.

Comment: Your code is really poorly indented which makes it very misleading.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I might try is rather than building the button list html as a string, create an array of [`i`,html] pairs or an object of {`i`: html} mappings, and then when doing `.html()` sort them and concatenate. It would at least remove the synchronicity as a variable.

**Edit**

A proof of concept: http://jsfiddle.net/mkb0fyco/

```
function randomDeferred(){
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    var promise = deferred.promise();

    window.setTimeout(function(){
        deferred.resolve();
    }, Math.random() * 3000 + 1000);

    return promise;
}

var dates = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'];
var buttons = [];
$(dates).each(function(i,e){
    $.when(randomDeferred()).then(function(){
        buttons[i] = e;
        $('body').empty();
        $(buttons).each(function(i,e){
            if(e) // has it been set?
            {
                $('body').append('<button>' + e + '</button>');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I have tried that approach. It is not also not working as expected.

Comment: @Mihir Are you sure then that `availableDates`/`formattedDates` are sorted?

Comment: Yes @ZJM, those were sorted.

Comment: @Mihir I think it's "impossible" that if `formattedDates` is sorted, and you tried explicitly concatenating the html in `i` order, the resulting output "can't" be sorted randomly. What sort of logging have you done to verify the status throughout the process? Is there any more information you could perhaps provide?

Comment: I have tried logging with console.log just before the closing of `then` method. Outside `then` method `dateButtons` variable not accesible.

Comment: @Mihir Why would `dateButtons` not be accessible outside `then`? I would just expect it to always be empty, if that's what you mean? When you log inside `then`, sure I could see how they could fire out of order. But that should be resolvable by what I proposed - storing them by index, and resorting each time `then` fires, rather than in order of completion/append.

Comment: Yes, this approach could be made to work. @ZJM, it seems you need to provide some illustrative code in order to persuade the OP.

Comment: @ryachza Yeah, i mean to say is `dateButtons` is coming as empty outside of then because of asynchronous. I am not sure how index will work here.

Comment: @Mihir I updated the answer with a proof of concept. The idea is to maintain a collection of buttons as the results complete in the order you want them and replacing them all each time any completes. One optimization I would recommend is building the HTML string and replacing the content rather than actually emptying/appending to reduce the number of costly DOM manipulation calls.

Answer (score 0):

There's no guarantee that the promises returned by `commonOperations.queryList()` will settle in the same order the calls were made.

There are various ways to ensure that the buttons are appended in the same order as the original data. Here are two ...

**1. Wait for all promises to settle, then render the buttons**

```
var getDatesAvailable = function() {
    var weekDays = masterConfigurations[0].DaysOfWeek.results;
    var advancedDays = masterConfigurations[0].DaysToShow;
    var todaysDate = new Date();
    var futureDate = new Date(todaysDate);
    futureDate.setDate(todaysDate.getDate() + advancedDays);
    var schoolCode = $('#selectedSchoolAddress').data('schoolCode') || "";

    // Here the array returned by `returnFinalDates()` is mapped to an array of promises. 
    // Each promise will deliver a jQuery-wrapped <button>.
    var promises = returnFinalDates(todaysDate, futureDate, weekDays).map(function(i, e) {
        var tDate = commonOperations.pad(e.getDate(), 2);
        var tMonth = commonOperations.pad((e.getMonth() + 1), 2);
        var isoDate = e.getFullYear() + "-" + tMonth + "-" + tDate + "T00:00:00.000z";
        var dates = {
            "displayDate": (tDate + "/" + tMonth),
            "dateObj": isoDate
        };
        var startDate = new Date(dates.dateObj).toISOString();
        var endDate = dates.dateObj.split("T")[0];
        endDate = (new Date(endDate + "T23:59:59.000z")).toISOString();

        // Return a promise into the `promises` array.
        return commonOperations.queryList("ITFS_Transact_School_Visits", "?$filter=((ITFSVisitDate gt '" + startDate + "') and (ITFSVisitDate lt '" + endDate + "') and (ITFSVisitSchoolCode eq '" + schoolCode + "'))", false)
        .then(function(bookings) {
            // The jQuery-wrapped button returned here becomes the value delivered by the promise pushed into the `promises` array.
            return $('<button type="button" class="btn btn-default dateButton add10Margin" data-date="' + dates.dateObj + '">' + dates.displayDate + '</button>')
            .prop('disabled', (bookings.d.results.length || 0) >= masterConfigurations[0].MaxBookingsPerSession);
        });
    });

    // When all the commonOperations.queryList() promises are fulfilled, 
    // loop through the delivered values (buttons) and append them, in order, to #displayDates.
    return $.when.apply(null, promises).then(function() {
        $("#displayDates").empty();
        $.each(arguments, function(i, $button) {
            $("#displayDates").append($button);
        });
    });
};
```

**2. Synchronously appended one container per button then asynchronously append each button to its container**

The closure formed by `function(i, e) {...}` ensures that each button is matched to the contanier created for it in the same turn of the `.map()` loop.

```
var getDatesAvailable = function() {
    var weekDays = masterConfigurations[0].DaysOfWeek.results;
    var advancedDays = masterConfigurations[0].DaysToShow;
    var todaysDate = new Date();
    var futureDate = new Date(todaysDate);
    futureDate.setDate(todaysDate.getDate() + advancedDays);
    var schoolCode = $('#selectedSchoolAddress').data('schoolCode') || "";
    var promises = returnFinalDates(todaysDate, futureDate, weekDays).map(function(i, e) {
        var tDate = commonOperations.pad(e.getDate(), 2);
        var tMonth = commonOperations.pad((e.getMonth() + 1), 2);
        var isoDate = e.getFullYear() + "-" + tMonth + "-" + tDate + "T00:00:00.000z";
        var dates = {
            "displayDate": (tDate + "/" + tMonth),
            "dateObj": isoDate
        };
        var startDate = new Date(dates.dateObj).toISOString();
        var endDate = dates.dateObj.split("T")[0];
        endDate = (new Date(endDate + "T23:59:59.000z")).toISOString();

        var $container = $("<span/>").appendTo("#displayDates"); // A span element that is synchronously appended to the #displayDates container.

        // Now return a promise into the `promises` array.
        return commonOperations.queryList("ITFS_Transact_School_Visits", "?$filter=((ITFSVisitDate gt '" + startDate + "') and (ITFSVisitDate lt '" + endDate + "') and (ITFSVisitSchoolCode eq '" + schoolCode + "'))", false)
        .then(function(bookings) {
             $('<button type="button" class="btn btn-default dateButton add10Margin" data-date="' + dates.dateObj + '">' + dates.displayDate + '</button>')
              .prop('disabled', (bookings.d.results.length || 0) >= masterConfigurations[0].MaxBookingsPerSession)
              .appendTo($container);
              // As there's nothing more to do below, there's no point returning a value here.
        });
    });

    // When all the commonOperations.queryList() promises are fulfilled, there's nothing more to do
    // except return an aggregated promise signifying successful completion (or a failure).
    return $.when.apply(null, promises);
};
```

Differences between the two approaches revolve mainly around the consequences of async errors.

1. Will append all buttons or none - any single failure will scupper the whole enterprise. If all are successful, all buttons will appear together, after the final promise resolves.
2. Will append every button successfully created even if one or more buttons fail. Buttons will appear one at a time, as the individual promises settle.

Taking things a bit further, in both cases, you could insert dummy buttons (or something else) in place of any failures, though the code would be slightly more involved.

Comment: This is interesting.. I will try and let you know. But how to learn these promises and the way you have written the functions? I want to understand more on the promises and their structures. Is there any resources available?

Comment: Tutorials and examples abound on the web. For jQuery, try 
[Deferred examples](https://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/deferreds/examples/)
or for navive javascript promises, try
[JavaScript Promises](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/), as already linked in the comments above, but ignore the "Bonus round" section at the end - it will only serve to confuse at this stage.